# Hover Details Expand to All or 10 Records

Tags: account, mini-page-layout, mousehover

I'd like for an Account-based Related List Hover Detail to include more than 5 records for users. How can I accomplish this? For myself, I see the complete list, or at least 12, for the records I was checking against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of field in related list are controlled by an option on the bottom of each object details page called Always show me fewer/more per related list. You can set manually this number by changing the value of `rowperlist` in the URL. I think the maximum number is 200. I don't think there is a way to mass update change this value for all your users, because it's more a user preference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, I am not talking about Related List records within the Page Layout. I'm talking about it being accessed via Hover at the top of the Record.

Comment: It's the same thing.